# TypeError: res.json is not a function when using require('fs');

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to pass contents for files I am reading via res.json. I think I am over writing my res function, but I dont see a fix.

```
    app.get('/uploads/', (res, req) => {
        dirname = './client/uploads'
      fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {

        console.log(filenames)
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          return;
        }
        filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
          if (filename != '.DS_Store'){
          fs.readFile(dirname + "/" + filename, 'utf-8', function(err, content) {
             res.json({content: content})

            if (err) {
              //onError(err);
              console.log(err)
              return;
            }

          });
        }
        });
      });
})
```

Comment: You seem to have parameter names swapped.

Answer (score 2):

You mis-matched the arguments of `/uploads` route handler, `req` is the first argument

```
app.get('/uploads/', (req, res) => {

    //...

})
```